# Having a Variable in a Render get transfered to the HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

Sorry for the confusing title, but I'm not really sure what the exact problem is because I don't know Ruby all that well. Anyway, on to the problem!

So I have a render:

```
<div class="form" id="dept_div">
     <span class="label search_label">Department:</span>
          <% query = "<option></option>" %>
             <% Department.all.each do |d| %>
                <% query << "<option>"+d.dept+"</option>" %>
             <% end %>

          <%=select_tag :major, query.html_safe,   class: "search_tag", id: "dept_drop" %>
 </div>
```

That I try and plug in over here:

```
<span class="su_label">
  <%= f.label :major %>
</span>
<% if !in_mobile_view? %>
  <div class = "su_textfield">
    <div class="checkbox">
    <% else %>
      <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="field_group">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <% end %>
        <!-- check privacy preferences to decide whether box should already be checked -->
        <% if !hasnoprefs && @user.privacy_prefs.include?("nomajor") %>
          <%= check_box_tag "major", 1, true %>
        <% else %>
          <%= check_box_tag "major" %>
        <% end %>
        <%= label_tag 'major', 'Hide' %>
        <% if !in_mobile_view? %>
        </div>
        <%= render 'courses/form_partials/majors' %>
</div>
    <% else %>
      <%= f.text_field :major, class: "settings_inputfield" %>
    </fieldset>
```

What I want is the variable major (which in the class User) to become the item selected from the render (which is a drop down menu). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
<%= f.collection_select :major, query, :id, :major, {:include_blank => 'None' } %>
```

Comment: It says `undefined method `map' for #<String:0x00000003cdd770>`

What does that mean?

Comment: Replace 'query' with 'query.html_safe'
     
          
     <%= f.collection_select :major, query.html_safe, :id, :major, {:include_blank => 'None' } %>

Comment: Try with an '@' infront of ALL query variables.

Comment: <%= f.collection_select :major, Department.all, :id, :major, {:include_blank => 'None' } %>